# why is string.split returning extra empty entries in this example?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a bit of code that takes a user input string date MM/DD/YYYY and refactors it to YYYYMMDD, then returns the refactored string.

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
      
    
      // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
      var dateParts = userDate.split(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);
      var day = dateParts[2],
        month = dateParts[1],
        year = dateParts[3];
        
        console.log(dateParts.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < dateParts.length; i++) {
          console.log(dateParts[i]);
        }
        console.log(dateParts);
        
      if (day > 0 && day <= 9)
        day = 0 + day;
      if (month > 0 && month <= 9)
        month = 0 + month;
      return year + month + day;
    }
    
    console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zaknaberrnon/gjrz5704/2/)
At first I thought that string.split() was returning a 1-based array, but then I discovered that in fact it's returning an array of length 5, with empty strings at userDate[0] and userDate[4] and I can't figure it out. Why is this happening? thanks!

Comment: You can `match` with this regex, see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gjrz5704/4/)

Comment: ^^ `split` is just the wrong tool here. When you `split`, the regex says where to split (without including what matched).

Comment: thanks! i just tried it with match and it works much better. I'd still like to know why split is returning the array with those empty strings at positions 0 and 4 though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
  console.log(userDate);
  var dateParts = userDate.split("/");
  return dateParts[2] + dateParts[0] + dateParts[1];
 }
console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here

- Replace the regex for `split` with `/\//`
- Reduce the `index` of each of the items

i.e.

```
var day = dateParts[1],
month = dateParts[0],
year = dateParts[2];
```

**Demo**

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
  var dateParts = userDate.split(/\//);
  var day = pad0(dateParts[1]), month = pad0(dateParts[0]), year = dateParts[2];
  return year + month + day;
}

function pad0(input)
{
   return ("0" + input).slice(-2);
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```